# Is Unreal engine or Unity better for high graphics low file size mobile games?

Tags: unity, 3d, unreal-4, mobile

My objective of learning game development is to make a 3d relatively high graphics mobile game but that should be in 150 mb. I don't know should I start with unity or unreal engine. I found that people say unreal engine is better for 3d games and unity is better for mobile game development. As I have no experience, can anyone suggest me an engine with some reasons?

Comment: Try both and see what works better for you. For compact results you might even be better off trying an alternative like Godot. But overall such questions are off-topic here, since this can be largely subjective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your making a mobile game that has to fit into 150 MB you probably won't be able to show the full graphics capabilities of any of those engines. As your objective is learning I would suggest you go with Unity as its much easier to get started and to find proper resources you will need for your game. Besides better* resources, Unity will be easier to learn.